# Read files in Android App using Google Drive API - fails

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google Drive in my Android Application - basically to read PDF files from Google Drive - but now just trying to connect and fetch any file from Drive.

So I did the following:

1. Created a new Google Cloud project, enabled Drive API and generated an API key and OAuth client ID (**both having the same SHA1 - is that correct?**)
   [image]
2. Used the following code on my MainActivity.kt:

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       private val fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
       private lateinit var  readButton: Button
       private var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null
       private var isFileRead = false
       private val accessDriveScope: Scope = Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE)
       private val scopeEmail: Scope = Scope(Scopes.EMAIL)

   private var launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
       {
           result ->
           if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
               val data: Intent? = result.data
               try{
                   val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                   task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                   checkForGooglePermissions()
               }
               catch (e: ApiException){

               }

           }
       }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       readButton = findViewById(R.id.read)

       readButton.setOnClickListener{
           isFileRead = true
           val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
               .requestEmail()
               .requestScopes(Scope(DRIVE_FILE))
               .build()

           googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso)

           val signInIntent = googleSignInClient?.signInIntent
           launcher.launch(signInIntent)
       }
   }

   private fun checkForGooglePermissions() {
       if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(
           GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
           accessDriveScope,
           scopeEmail
           )){
           GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
               this,
               1,
               GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
               accessDriveScope,
               scopeEmail
           )
       }
       else {       
           lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch { driveSetUp() }
       }
   }

   private suspend fun driveSetUp(){
           val mAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)

           val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
               this,
               Collections.singleton(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE)
           )

           credential.selectedAccount = mAccount?.account

           val googleDriveService = Drive.Builder(
               NetHttpTransport(),
               GsonFactory(),
               credential
           ).setApplicationName("My Drive Test").build()

           if (isFileRead){
               //Read from drive
               withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
                   try {
                       val fileListJob = async {listDriveFiles(googleDriveService)}
                       val fileList = fileListJob.await()
                       for (item in fileList){
                           Log.d("MyLog", item.name)
                       }
                   }
                   catch (e: Exception){
                       //Handle error
                   }
               }
           }
       }

   private fun listDriveFiles(mDriveService: Drive): List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File>
       {
           var result: FileList
           var pageToken: String? = null       
           do {
               result = mDriveService.files().list()
                   .setQ("mimeType=text/plain")
                   .setSpaces(DRIVE)
                   .setFields(fields)
                   .setPageToken(pageToken)
                   .execute()
               pageToken = result.nextPageToken
           } while (pageToken != null)

           return result.files
       }
   }
   ```
3. Once running the application it prompts me to connect to my Google account but then it fails in "val fileListJob = async {listDriveFiles(googleDriveService)}" with the following response:
   [image]

**[Edit 1:]**

The only link between my Android app and the Drive API is that I added my android package name to both API Key and OAuth Client ID:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I do have an API key..

**[Edit 2]:**

I followed up on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) and also had to use getAccountsByType() as indicated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify) but unfortunately while using:

```
val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(this) // "this" references the current Context
val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

I get an empty list (even though I have 3 accounts defined in my mobile phone). So instead I tried using this:

```
val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.accounts
```

and it returned back 1 account (my main gmail address) and it shows its type as

> com.osp.app.signin

What should I do next in order to login to my Drive account? I didn't find any complete instruction on how to do so - would really appreciate your assistance.

P.S.: I have the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Where are you using your API key?

Comment: @ryankuck I followed many online videos and blogs, and except for adding my Android package name to both of API key and OAuth client ID - I don't know what else should link my Android app to the Drive API. Please see my "Edit 1" above

Comment: I see, I added a possible answer below. In general I see also that there are many tutorials which each only provide part of the solution. My recommendation is first make sure you have sign-in working with Google, and check you have the OAuth token from them. Next if that is successful the answer below should allow you to access a google api

Comment: Some are uploading their code to Github, many have very similar solutions. for instance:
https://github.com/mesadhan/google-drive-app/blob/master/README.md
Looking at the their code I don't see any HttpURLConnection / addRequestProperty. Why is that? Do they overcome this in a different way?

Comment: They are using GoogleSignInClient which is deprecated https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: I've edited my initial post - please see Edit 2 above.

Comment: Ok it looks like you’re making a lot of progress. From the answer below I see you need 4 credentials to make the api call successfully. #1 is the api key that you have access to in the console screenshotted above. Actually “The first three come from the Google API Console website.” #4 is the OAuth token that your latest changes can get by calling AccountManager.getAuthToken(). Let me know how the google api call goes!

Answer (score 0):

From [the "Authenticate to OAuth2 services" docs](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate):

> The Google APIs require you to supply four values with each request: ***the API key***,
> the client ID, the client secret, and the auth key. The first three
> come from the Google API Console website. The last is the string value
> you obtained by calling AccountManager.getAuthToken(). You pass these
> to the Google Server as part of an HTTP request.

```kotlin
val url = URL("https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=$your_api_key")
val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
conn.apply {
    addRequestProperty("client_id", your client id)
    addRequestProperty("client_secret", your client secret)
    setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth $token")
}
```

> If the request returns an HTTP error code of 401, then your token has been denied. As mentioned in the last section, the most common reason for this is that the token has expired. The fix is simple: call AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken() and repeat the token acquisition process one more time.